# Whatever happened to closed_reason?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed

When pulling back info on a closed question, I have come to expect `closed_reason` to be a present key if there's a `closed_date`. It seems that as of recently this is no longer true.

Proof: https://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/questions/164867?pagesize=10&site=askubuntu

What happened to this key? I need it. Can it be reintroduced please?

**Edit:** Just noticed this is [still in the API documentation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/question), so I guess this is more of a bug. Again, please add this back to the API. We need it as part of Ask Ubuntu's ongoing cleanup effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fun one.

Changes behind the scenes to how closed reasons are handled caused the API to stop getting a real reason and start getting a null one.  This was just different enough from *failing* to get a reason that it went unnoticed, oy.

This was fixed in the most recent build.